# foreignkey not saved in nested model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

i have two tables in my application

rfp.rb

```
            has_many :rfp_hors
            attr_accessible :rfp_hors_attributes
            accepts_nested_attributes_for :rfp_hors, :allow_destroy => true
```

rfp_hor.rb

```
      attr_accessible   :numberofmenu_est_hours,
     :numberofmenu_act_hours,
     :browser_est_hours,
     :browser_act_hours,
     :numberofpage_est_hours,
     :numberofpage_act_hours,
     :rfp_id

belongs_to :rfp
```

when i submit rfp_hors the parameter shows as follows  in console

```
              Parameters: {"rfp_hor"=>{"ecommerce_est_hours"=>"7", "rfp_id"=>"13", "designcomplexity_est_hours"=>"3", "browser_est_hours"=>"4", "framworks_est_hours"=>"5", "cms_est_hours"=>"6"}, "utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Create Rfp hor", "authenticity_token"=>"XXgQlufpBP2lvcde/EiFIx93aM5Ov47MNFqsCkLun2Y="}
```

and controller
rfps.rb

```
    def show
        @rfp = Rfp.find(params[:id])
    @rfp_hor = RfpHor.new
    end
```

rfp_hors.rb

```
     def create
              @rfp_hor = RfpHor.create(params[:rfp_hor])

respond_to do |format|
  if @rfp_hor.save
   format.html { redirect_to rfp_url(@rfp_hor.rfp_id), :notice => 'rfp hour was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @rfp_hor, :status => :created, :location => @rfp_hor }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @rfp_hor.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

every thing saves fine in databse aceept rfp_id in rfp_hors
any help would be great  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is because you are initializing the variable `@rfp_hor` as new independent object in the rfps controller when would you initialize only the varbiale `@rfp`, you could try of this way:

```
def edit 
    @rfp = Rfp.find(params[:id])
end
```

on your update action of the same controller, you don't have to change nothing, and you can put this code in your form:

```
<%= form_for @rfp do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for : rfp_hors do |item| %>
      <%= item.field_one :field %>
      <%= item.field_two :field %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in this way you can to receive the params as nested form in the same controller in the update action and you can show the params of this mode:

```
Parameters: {"rfp"=>{"rfp_hors_attributes"=>{"ecommerce_est_hours"=>"7", "rfp_id"=>"13", "designcomplexity_est_hours"=>"3", "browser_est_hours"=>"4", "framworks_est_hours"=>"5", "cms_est_hours"=>"6"}}, "utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Create Rfp hor", "authenticity_token"=>"XXgQlufpBP2lvcde/EiFIx93aM5Ov47MNFqsCkLun2Y="}
```